Access a web service just by host name, not by IP address
I have a small network in which I have setup a Windows server with an IP address and hostname. The users in my network should be able to access the web service that is offered by this Windows server.
How can I prevent users from accessing this web service using IP address, so that they can access this web service only by hostname?

I have a way to do that:

Host the web-service on another port. (Not 80)
Run nginx to serve the web-service on domain (server_name) and use proxy_pass to point to the web-service port.

